# Best software for visualising data in a 3D space

Tags: data-visualization, 3d, data

I need to show a collection of data and would like to do this in a 3D space which could be interacted with by viewers.

Can either be cloud based or local software.

Comment: Have you looked at PowerBI or Public Tableau, lots of tools for displaying different data. PowerBI would be the fastest to setup.

Comment: Currently looking PowerBI

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend PowerBI overall, if you have some advanced knowledge with computers and some coding experience you could try using GraphQL to visualise your data in very fancy ways if you have the time.

Comment: Thank you! PowerBI looks great, currently just trying it out now